# possible BUG on python-config ?! it doesn't print the full path of when using --ldflags

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, makefile, python-config

```
$ python-config --ldflags
-L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config -ldl -framework CoreFoundation -lpython2.7 -u _PyMac_Error Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
```

it prints `Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python` and not `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python`

when trying to use it in a `Makefile` it doesn't work with the `python-config --ldflags` but if I take the output and changes `Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python` to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python` it works perfectly.

- I want to avoid a solution which parses the `python-config` output in
  the makefile.
- I am using `gcc version 4.2.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug, and it was fixed three weeks ago: http://bugs.python.org/issue16848. The fix will ship with the 2.7.4 release, which is scheduled to go live on April 6.